# How does Stackoverflow comment system work

Tags: design, architecture, distributed-system

When someone comments on my question/answer/comment I will see the notification from the inbox, and it also shows under my response tab. Later when the comment is edited, the comment shown under the response tab changes; when the comment is deleted, the comment disappears from response tab as well. And the inbox message updates correspondingly during the process.

I think the system sends the notification through the queue service, and at the same time push the comment to my response tab. After that my account tries to pull the system periodically to update any changes (edit/delete). Is my understanding correct? Will it be a bottleneck for the system if so many users account pulls at the same time?

Comment: When you load a page on Stack Overflow, your browser opens a web socket connection. When changes are made to a post, the server sends a notification over the web socket and your browser retrieves new information. It's not a bottleneck because web sockets are designed specifically for this purpose. The server handling them can manage connections to hundreds or thousands of clients at once.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262045/is-performance-the-only-reason-not-to-use-signalr-websockets-entirely-in-lieu

Comment: @DanWilson there are separate parts of the system - I think the question is about the server side, not the network connection